# Local Database file not attached

Tags: c#, sql

I am using sql server 2008 R2  and sql server managment studio .
I want to attach the local database file at run time .
I provided the local database path via texbox to the connection string . 
But it gives me error

> invalid object name .

```
       con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=
    (LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=" + databasepathtextbox.Text + "; 
    Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets =True;");
```

and command to insert data:

```
      con.Open();
         cmd=new SqlCommand(" insert into  Firsttimecheck (checkfilepath) 
     Values('" + textBox1.Text + "')", con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
```

And the path which i get via texbox as

```
     D:\\data\\datainfo\\schoinfo\\Database1.mdf
```

Please help, how to add local database file path at run time?

Comment: which line of code is causing which exception? (please provide all necessary details). *plus here goes the usual, obligatory not-safe-for-scripting rant: do not inject user input into query text*

Comment: the exception through on     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: but when i remove the run time and give actual path then it work

Comment: ok so when you check after con.Open() in SQL studio, is the database there, and accessible? and does it contain the `Firsttimecheck` table?

Comment: no i m creating in local database

Comment: then it work but i want to add the local database file path at run time

Comment: Does your local database file actually have the `Firsttimecheck` table?

Answer (score 0):

Finnaly I figure out the error . The error was \\ I replace it with \ and it worked